# Get ranges of edited lines in vim buffer

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use [vim-codefmt](https://github.com/google/vim-codefmt) and want it to only format the lines which were changed on save. Is there a way to grab a list of the lines which were changed?

Comment: Consider asking on the issue tracker.

Comment: It's on their to-do, but I'm asking a more general question which is how to grab ranges of modified lines in a buffer. Is this possible?